# How do I use bootstrap slider in Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, node-webkit, nativeapplication

I am getting the following error when I use bootstrap slider
(https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) in my Electron(http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/) app :

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Slider is not a function"

Earlier I was also struggling with using Jquery but solved it using : 
https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/254 :

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('/path/to/jquery');
instead of regular :

The reason quoted was 
Query contains something along this lines:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
  // set jQuery in `module`
} else {
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

I don't understand what is the right way to use it for bootstrap the slider.

I could see that bootstrap-slider.js has a component dealing with "module" which might be causing the anomaly just like in jquery.

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
            define(["jquery"], factory);
    } else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
            var jQuery; 
            try {   
                    jQuery = require("jquery");
            } catch (err) { 
                    jQuery = null; 
            }       
            module.exports = factory(jQuery);
    } else {
            root.Slider = factory(root.jQuery);
    }
```

Please tell me how to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. Include jQuery and Bootstrap slider regularly in the index.html page with a script after each to make them global like so:

```html
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
        window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;
    }
</script>
<script src="path/to/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
        window.Slider = module.exports;
    }
</script>
```

2. Use `require` to include jQuery and Slider whenever you need them

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
var Slider = require('bootstrap-slider');
```

Comment: That worked for jQuery, but not for slider. It still keeps saying that slider is not a function. I'm on Electron 1.7.12, jQuery 1.11.0, Bootstrap 3.3.5 and Bootstrap Slider 9.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Found that solution below yesterday. Worked for me both with jQuery and Bootstrap Slider. Credits on the bottom.

**A better an more generic solution IMO:**

```
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = 
undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

**Benefits**

- Works for both browser and electron with the same code
- Fixes issues   for ALL 3rd-party libraries (not just jQuery) without having to specify each one
- Script Build / Pack Friendly (i.e. Grunt / Gulp all
  scripts into vendor.js)
- Does NOT require node-integration to be false

source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by placing *my* path to jquery in the bootstrap-slider.js

`Line 41: jQuery = require("my/path/to/jquery-2.1.4.min.js");`

This is probably the wrong solution, but hopefully a bad idea can lead to a good one :)